# different meaning between these two sentences based on the position of 'yet'

Tags: sentence-meaning

Are they exactly same or somehow different?

(1) The places contain many forms of life that have not **yet** been discovered.

(2) The places contain many forms of life that have not been discovered **yet**.

Answer (score 3):

The question is really whether the adverb *yet* modifies the same verb construction *have (not) been discovered*. It does and there's no perceivable nuance.

It's like comparing: *He's not yet home* with *He's not home yet*.

However, it can happen that the placement of the modifier in the sentence alters the meaning:

*He does not understand clearly what you are saying* is different from:

*He does not understand what you are saying clearly* because clearly modifies different verbs in these two examples.

Comment: Ronald, Now I fully understand that. Thank you for your kind answer. Have a great day and happy new year!